# How to convert yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss into mm-dd-yyyy hh:mi:ss in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper, varchar2

I have a `varchar` column and I want to convert `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss` into `mm-dd-yyyy hh:mi:ss` and cast it into a date. How can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert the string into a date:

```
to_date (the_string, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
```

If you then want that to be formatted as a string in format mm-dd-yyyy hh:mi:ss:

```
to_char (to_date (the_string, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss'), 'mm-dd-yyyy hh:mi:ss')
```

Comment: +1 and if date in 24-hour format `hh` must be replaced with `hh24`